# how to access a namespace variable directly in the event bind function

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

I'm rewriting my JS code to make it more clear and precise. I define one module in namespace and not able to pass the same variable in that bind function, see below code:

```
// Gmap Autocomplete initialization and reset function
var gMapPlace = gMapPlace || {};
gMapPlace.geoAutocomplete = (function(){
    var detail = {
        searchEle : null,
        autocompleteEle : null,
        autocompleteLsr : null,
        init : function(searchEle){
            this.searchEle = searchEle;
            this.autocompleteEle = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchEle);
            this.autocompleteLsr = google.maps.event.addListener(this.autocompleteEle, 'place_changed', function () {
                var data = gMapPlace.geoAutocomplete.data; 
                // ################################
                var place = data.autocompleteEle.getPlace(); // any way to reference simple 'this.autocompleteEle' here
                // ################################
                var address = place.formatted_address;
                var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
                var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
                var mesg = "Address: " + address;
                mesg += "\nLatitude: " + latitude;
                mesg += "\nLongitude: " + longitude;
                alert(mesg);
            });

        },
        reset : function(){
            if(isNotBlank(this.searchEle)){
                google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(this.searchEle);
            }
        }
    };
    return{
        data : detail
    };

}());
```

As per the above code, I've a bind function at `this.autocompleteLsr` which runs when that particular event happen, when I directly use `var place = this.autocompleteEle.getPlace()`, then it gives `undefined` error run-time. Now in order to work I code it to get the value by iterating over the namespace object like

```
var data = gMapPlace.geoAutocomplete.data; 
// ################################
var place = data.autocompleteEle.getPlace();// any way to reference simple 'this.autocompleteEle' here
// ################################
```

Is there any other way to reference module variables at run-time or that's the only way here.

Comment: You could use an `arrow` function, which will allow you to use the enclosures `this` inside the function as arrow functions do not generate their own `this`. You could also just use `detail.autocompleteEle` in the function as by that time it will have a value filled.

Comment: Well my problem is not with `this`, at the runtime when that event happen how can I use variable `gMapPlace.geoAutocomplete.data.autocompleEle` without iterating through like because this function is initialized within this namespace context, why can't I directly use the variable like `this.autocompleteEle`.

Comment: Then you have not shown the correct runtime code. If you do something like `eventHandlerFunction.bind( gMapPlace.geoAutocomplete.data )` you should be able to use `this` inside the `eventHandlerFunction`. For some reason I feel you might have overcomplicated this a bit.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree on that we can run-time pass this variable there and then refer it with `this` keyword. but i just wanted to sure that Is there any other way we can refer this variable, other then what I did. I'm a bit confuse like is it the right way or not which I did.

Comment: You get use a `getter` for this? `data = { get autoCompletelEle(){ /* code to get element, return element */ }`? But if the function is asynchornous, you won't be able to do that.

Comment: got your point, thanks